# Set form field as invalid from HostListener event

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am using angular 4 and pretty new to it. I ma using template driven forms. I have a form field on which i have some pattern match. So i have some events registered like

```
@HostListener('blur', ['$event'])
    onBlur(event) {
        // this.validateFormControl.markAsTouched();
        console.log(event);
        console.log(this.elementRef)
console.log(this.elementRef.nativeElement)
```

I want to check whats the status of form elements inside it like is it valid or invalid and do some extra checking and set form element as invalid based on some condition from inside of it. How can i set form element as invalid from inside of this function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Template Driven Forms`](https://angular.io/guide/forms) are very limited compared to [`Reactive Forms`](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) and I strongly recommend using the latter because of robust API behind it.

But if you really need to hack with `Template Driven Forms` to add some custom validations you can experiment with using [`setCustomValidity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/setCustomValidity) and `checkValidity` methods of form elements.

I don't recommend creating any programmatical validation for [`Template Driven Forms`](https://angular.io/guide/forms), because this is not the way they were originally designed, instead, use [`Reactive Forms`](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) and read [this guide](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation).

Comment: I have only 2 form fields. That's the reason i used template driven forms.